# How to know subcategory of category Dropdown Selection?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc

How can i Categorized in database uisng dropdownlist onces

I click INVORG category and show the available in DEPTCODE?

```html
using Json

 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetDEPTCODE(string id)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> states = new List<SelectListItem>();
           ///

//I got Error Code, can you please define my wrong code and correct thanks

            states = from u in _db.USERGROUPs where u.INVORG == id 
                     select(new SelectListItem {Text =u.INVORG, Value = u.DEPTCODE});


       return Json(new SelectList(states, "Value", "Text"));
        }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#INVORG").change(function () {
            $("#DEPTCODE").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDEPTCODE")', // we are calling json method
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#INVORG").val() },
                // here we are get value of selected INVORG and passing same value
                success: function (states) {
                    // states contains the JSON formatted list
                    // of states passed from the controller
                    $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                        $("#DEPTCODE").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                        state.Text + '</option>');
                        // here we are adding option for States
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your method to HttpGet as you are getting data.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetDEPTCODE(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items= new List<SelectListItem>();
         return Json(new { data = items}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

change your script as below

```
$("#INVORG").change(function () {
        $("#DEPTCODE").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDEPTCODE")', // we are calling json method
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#INVORG").val() },
            // here we are get value of selected INVORG and passing same value
            success: function (data) {
                // states contains the JSON formatted list
                // of states passed from the controller
                $("#DEPTCODE").html('');
                $.each(data["data"], function (key, value) {

                $("#DEPTCODE").append($("<option>
         </option>").val(value.Value).html(value.Text));

            });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: Hi sir your code didn't work , under the invorg does not appear

Comment: this answer was posted for your original question..how can you change the whole question?? @ThePrograMMER